# SwiftUI Form struct not recognized by Xcode 11

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

In one of the WWDC talks, the devs used a struct called `Form` (I can't remember which talk but if someone knows and comments the talk number, that would be nice). The link to `Form` in the Apple Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form), but when I tried to use one in a project, Xcode didn't recognize it:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Form'

I know that some features from the WWDC SwiftUI talks are not currently available, but I wanted to make sure it wasn't a bug or something I am missing, because it does have a page in the Apple SwiftUI Documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_2_release_notes), support for the `Form` view was added in beta 2, which was released today (6/18/19). Download the latest Xcode beta from Apple and you should be able to use the `Form` view!

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it was released today.